# VB Class defined in App_Code and set to Compile is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got a class defined in my App_Code folder, and the build action is set to Compile, however it's still throwing the `Type 'Global.XXX.xxx.MyControl' is not defined.` error.

Class:

```
Namespace XXX.xxx
    Public Class MyControl
        Inherits TextBox
        ...code...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Page Useage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xxx" Namespace="XXX.xxx" %>
...
<xxx:MyControl runat="server" id="control" />
```

Any ideas?  Again, I've set this class's build action to Compile, but it's just not taking.

Comment: Where does `Global.` namespace come from? I do not see that in your code.

Comment: That is an excellent question.  Removing it from the designer.aspx.vb file got it to compile.  Strange, considering that's an automatically generated file, but I'll take it!  Thanks!